# Why does an object change in a non object when i add something to a query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a part of this query (this works):

```
group_concat(`tag`.`name`) as `tags`
```

I changed it to this to add spaces as seperators instead of a comma:

```
group_concat(`tag`.`name` ASC SEPARATOR '&nbsp; &nbsp;') as `tags`
```

Now it doesn't work anymore with this error:

```
Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in.
```

This is my php loop to get the results:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql_query);
   while($row = $result ->fetch_assoc()) {
 .. the rest
```

Does anyone know why the $result suddenly is not a object anymore?

Comment: Probably because `$conn->query($sql_query)` failed - a.k.a you broke your query.

Comment: Non Object normally means you broke the query. Did you try running that query in phpMyAdmin (or something similiar) before asking the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added `ASC` and the `SEPARATOR` on [`GROUP CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). The `SEPARATOR` part is fine but the `ASC` can't be used without the `ORDER BY`. So your query isn't valid. You can use the following query instead:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(`tag`.`name` ORDER BY `tag`.`name` ASC SEPARATOR '&nbsp; &nbsp;') AS `tags`
```

You are using [`mysqli::query`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) to execute the query and get the result. In case your query isn't valid and can't be executed you get `false` instead of a [`mysqli_result`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object. So you can improve your code like the following to make sure you only access the object if it is available:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql_query);

//check the return value.
if ($result === false) {
    echo 'something went wrong';
} elseif ($result === true) {
    echo 'query executed successfully (not a SELECT statement)';
} else {
    while($row = $result ->fetch_assoc()) {
        //...
    }
}
```

**Note:** You don't need the `$result === true` condition if you are using a `SELECT` statement.